# Radiobutton IN tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.x

I m creating a GUI for a simple quiz and I want my answer to be checked in radiobutton . But the problem is that I can not mark or unmark it , its always set up marked . my code is

```
R1=Radiobutton(win,text= 'option1',command =sel1)
```

My function sel1 is as follow :

```
 def sel1():
      global ans
      ans = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see [from the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm) the `radiobutton` is used to select one out of many, whcih as I understand will always require one button to be marked. It's possible you need [CheckButton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm).

EDIT: As it turned out the problem was to set common variable for all radio buttons as mentioned in the docs linked above.

Comment: I have made 4 radiobuttons for 4 options similarly , I can not post screenshot since I have made my program in school lab computer . my problem is that all fours are always selected and nothing works on clicking the radio button.

Comment: Don't they need some packing or grouping? I see the example uses `pack()` method which is similar to what is used in other plkaces like HTML forms.

Comment: For packing I wrote : R1.pack()

Comment: And if you give a common variable: `Radio buttons are usually used in groups, where all buttons in the group share a common variable. `?

Comment: OK , I will try it and will post if problem still persist ,hope it will work with defining a common variable with it. Thanks

Comment: I'll keep my fingers crossed. But if it does not, please update your question with all the information we've mentioned here so that anyone else can help you without digging through my anwer.

Comment: I have got a video on YouTube where youtuber faces the same problem : Video is named : Basic Python Tutorial 40 : Radio button Program. if you can watch and tell what is the problem , I will be thankful to you

Comment: You'll have to give a minimal verifiable example of your code then.

Comment: I got my problem as you said to set a common variable ,I just have not used it . so , all were selected . I also will have to set value different for each radio button . Like R1=Radiobutton (win,text='option1',value=1,variable=1,command=sel1).   It is working now.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad i could help :) Please mark my answer then. I've updated it.